# Testing ajax requests using jasmine returns TypeError

Tags: javascript, ajax, unit-testing, jasmine, jquery-deferred

The description of the task. I want to  test the code that loads a list of resources using $.get.

So, the source code:

```
fetchTemplates: function(list, cb){
    var promises = [],
        $container = $('#templates');
    Object.keys(list).forEach(function(tplSelector){
        if($(tplSelector).length > 0){ return; }

        var promise = $.get(list[tplSelector]);
        promise
            .done(function(tplHtml){

                $container.append(tplHtml);
            })
            .fail(function(){
                console.warn('Template "' + tplSelector + " not found by url:" + list[tplSelector]);
            });

        promises.push( promise );
    });

    return $.when.apply($,promises).done(cb);
}
```

The test suite:

```
it("Correct template fetching", function (done) {
        var fetchResult = viewManager.fetchTemplates({
            '#helpTpl': 'somecorrectaddress'
        });
        fetchResult.done(function () {
            expect(true).toBeTruthy();
            done();
        });
        fetchResult.fail(function () {
            expect(false).toBeTruthy();
            done();
        });
});
```

What it generates. Test passes, but generates an error:
TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'this.results_.addResult')
at jasmine.js?2348

So, the test case marks as passed. But whole test suite still generates the error above (and this method is the only one async, other parts are trivial to test). My thought was that since the tested method contains async operations and promises - results were not properly handled and thus TypeError. So I added jasmine async "done()" to handle the issue - unfortunately nothing changed. Also worth noting that if I leave only one test in the suite using "iit" - no error is generated. Search didn't find similar cases. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your async calls in 'runs()' with 'waitsFor()' after, read the documentation [here](http://jasmine.github.io/1.3/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support). I've never worked with jquery, but try something like the following inside your it function:

```
var done = false;
var that = this;

runs( function() {
    //your async test goes here
    that.done = true;
});

waitsFor( function() {
    return that.done;
}, "async code failed", 2000);
```